# Expo on Android simulator could not run, Something went wrong

Tags: android, react-native, port, expo, android-virtual-device

I want to run react native app on Android simulator. When I run `expo start`, Metro Builder opens on the chrome (`http://localhost:19002/`), Then I click on the `Run on Android device/emulator`. App installs on the simulator but Expo app gets this error:
[image: EXPO PORT]
I think this is for ports. How can I solve this error? I upgrade react native and do many issues from StackOverflow. but problem not solve.

[image: Metro Builder]

Comment: can you try this?  `open terminal => adb tcpip 5555`

Comment: @hongdevelop yes, it says: restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

Comment: Has the problem been resolved? If not you can try `exp android`

Comment: @hongdevelop no, it shows the same error. something wrong...

Answer (score 10):

When you are running on a simulator, you need to run `expo start --android`. The usual `expo start` is only for connected devices. Also you might want to use `Tunnel` instead of `LAN` connection if you think your network might have firewalls blocking issues.

Answer (score 1):

In react-native this could be a lot of things, but if you try running it in tunnel, do you still get the error ?, if so try deleting node modules and run npm install again. do you have physical android device ? Then try scanning to barcode with you camera and see if it runs on an actual device. unfortunatly expo with android specifically has a few issues that are hard to debug.

Comment: I just run sample react native project. I can't run on iOS simulator in mac and android simulator on windows.

Answer (score 1):

In the metro bundler, choose connection type "Tunnel" and copy and send the URL to your phone. If you then click on it on your phone, it should redirect to the expo app. After that it got unstuck and I could finally use it normally with the QR code again!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your firewall. Otherwise you can try changing the port by defining a .exprc file containing:

```
{
  "manifestPort": 8000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to `Settings > Network & Internet > Turn off & on Airplane mode` and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall exist Expo Client on android / ios emulator.
then reload the project and press a to run on android emulator